# video tag can not play in Chrome 58

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

This link demo for upload file:
https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/
After upload video cannot play video 
It's work on FF, Edge but GC 58 not work!
video tag like this:

```
<video controls="" ngf-src="!files[0].$error && files[0]"></video>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the linked site does not work in Chrome 58?

Comment: It's demo. i use video tag it's not working.
i try paste link: blob:[url] it's error on GC but FF, Edge not error

Comment: File a bug then?

Comment: Video tag cannot play video. File upload success. no error

Comment: I am also having the same issue. This appears to be a bug with Chrome 58 having a problem with non-formatted metadata. If the meta-data is not formatted correctly Chrome 58 will not play the video. I have tested this with local files, and files hosted on a server. This was working on previous versions of Chrome, and is currently working on IE and Firefox. If you use ffmpeg to format the video using "-movflags faststart" the videos will play.